# How to verify Dataflow Runner v2 is being used?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Dataflow docs show how to enable [Dataflow Runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2)

> run your job with the following flag: --experiments=use_runner_v2

My system is complex so it's hard to know whether the flag is being set properly. Is there a way to see in the gcp UI whether v2 is being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, the best way is for you to check your experiments. If the `use_runner_v2` experiment is activated, then Dataflow is using V2.

Unfortunately, experiments are hidden by default (see [fix to un-hide](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/22207)). **AS A WORKAROUND** you can create your own `PipelineOption` interface with a `List<String> getExperiments()` method - and this will make sure that they show up in the UI.

[image]

---

A few more details, and using logs to figure this out:

In Runner V2, we use a 'runner harness' that is written in C++, and not in Java as usual. In the logs you can look for logs like:

- In streaming: `Executing: /opt/google/dataflow/streaming_harness_main`
- In Batch `Executing: /opt/google/dataflow/harness_main`

As opposed to a `java -jar` command.

In general, you can look for `harness` or `harness-startup` logs in the logging of your job. If there aren't `harness` logs, then your job is **NOT Runner V2**.

---

For what it's worth, it should be easier to do this. I'll request to add a feature to log it more clearly / show it in the UI.

Comment: In the future we need to be more explicit about this. I'll work with the team to make sure we're showing the runner information more prominently.